# Bootstrap switch doesn´t works

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am starting with  Bootstrap switch.

I have used the demos from http://www.jque.re/plugins/version3/bootstrap.switch/

The problem is that the switch doesn´t shows. It shows only a standard checkbox.

```
<div class="make-switch" data-on="primary" data-off="info">
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
</div>
```

I also have included the css and js staff.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/crtLwdg4/

What am I missing here?

Comment: It appears you do not have jQuery included in your fiddle which makes me think you don't have it included in your html.  jQuery needs to be included above the bootstrap includes.

Comment: In my local pc, I have included it. But I just included in JSFiddle and it did no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added this to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crtLwdg4/3/) and it seems the appearance has changed.

```
$(function() {
    $('.make-switch').bootstrapSwitch();
});
```

It seems you need to initialize the switch manually. I have only taken a glance at the docs but this actually changed the appearance of the checkbox.

UPDATE

I was able to get it working by adding a name property to the input and changing the jquery accordingly. see this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crtLwdg4/7/).

Comment: It appears now,  why it is not changing to on and off after clicked?